# Files and Folders are not opening in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: nautilus, files, directory

When I tried to open Nautilus from Terminal it shows me this error

(org.gnome.Nautilus:12411): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: 22:28:20.256: Settings schema 'org.freedesktop.Tracker.FTS' is not installed
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)

what should I do can anyone tell me??

Answer (score 0):

This is file [is contained in `tracker`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=org.freedesktop.Tracker.FTS) package, you have to reinstall it with:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall tracker
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! it worked